# Java - Find most specific exception superclass from among a set

Tags: java, exception

Let's say I have a set of exception classes, eg:

```
Exception
RuntimeException
IllegalArgumentException
IOException
FileNotFoundException
```

When given an exception class as an argument, I want to find the class from the set that is the most specific superclass of my given class. So if I'm given InvalidKeyException, I want to find IllegalArgumentException and not Exception or RuntimeException. If the given class is my set, I want to return the class itself (providing IOException returns IOException, etc). How can I do this in Java? The JVM (or compiler) must solve this problem every time there is a try block with multiple catch statements, but I can't find out how to do it given a set and an argument.

Much thanks in advance :)

EDIT: Clarification. The exception is not thrown, I have an instance of it that I am provided as an argument to my method (I could throw it manually sure, but I'd rather not as that is inelegant/bad performance)

Comment: May I ask why you are doing this? Sounds like this might be an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: What have you attempted so far?

Comment: Just catch them all. If you have any out of order, the compiler will tell you which ones. You don't want to write code to support this at runtime.

Comment: @Vince Emigh - Could certainly be an XY problem. I'm writing a JAX-RS exception handler, and I want to reduce boilerplate since I handle them all the same - I get a status code, error code, and description, then format them into a response for the client. In the past I've handled this by having one abstract exception handler and a subclass for each type of exception I want to handle. This made my classes tiny, but I still had to have one for each Exception type, which is a lot. I was hoping to have one handler catching all exceptions that looks up information about them in a map.

Comment: See https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/faces/context/ExceptionHandler.html. @YoungSpice haven't tried anything yet, an algorithm to do this wouldn't be that complicated but I don't want to write/maintain it myself. I'm hoping there's some code out there that can do this for me already.

Comment: I still don't see why you need this. Just catch the most general exception, then look at the actual exception type. You don't need to rank them yourself, which requires a topological sort.

Comment: @EJP That would be fine, except the exception type might not be in my set. For example with the set which I have listed above, if I get an InvalidKeyException, I need to look up the information for IllegalArgumentException instead.

Comment: I agree the use case sounds dubious.  Trying to interpret a polymorphic type can be very complicated.  You shouldn't need to do anything more complicated than call a logger.  If you need different behaviors, those should probably be handled when the exception is thrown.

Comment: I need to do more than call a logger - see my explanation above about returning appropriate status codes. Exceptions can be thrown from parts of code that I do not own or should not know about how those exceptions are expected to be handled. Handling exceptions at the top layer is idiomatic for the framework I'm using.

Comment: You should do that with polymorphism.  Make a new type, `MyException` and add the status codes and what-not there.

Comment: The exceptions are thrown by parts of the code that know nothing about statuses. Let's say MyException is thrown by MyComputationPackage. It's a breakage of encapsulation for MyComputationPackage to have any idea about whether that exception maps to a 400 or 500 HTTP status, or even aware that it's used as part of a web server. Four months from now it may be separated from the JAX-RS application entirely to satisfy a different use case. It shouldn't have to be refactored to make that happen.

Comment: You should catch those exceptions when they occur, and repackage them in an exception with the appropriate information stored.  My concern is that a `JaxRSException` (for example) will be a 500 status code at one point in your web server, but a 400 status code if it occurs somewhere else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a method that does what you want (I think).  Be aware that this is very brittle and if the structure of your inheritance is at all complicated, this probably isn't going to be able to resolve the type to your satisfaction.  I really encourage you to re-think how you are solving this.

```
public class Dubious
{
   static private List<Class<? extends Exception>> types = 
           Arrays.asList( Exception.class, FileNotFoundException.class,
                   IOException.class, IllegalArgumentException.class,
                   RuntimeException.class );

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      processException( new InvalidKeyException() );
      processException( new SocketException() );
      processException( new IllegalArgumentException() );
      processException( new Exception() );
   }

   public static void processException( Exception ex ) {
      Class<?> exType = ex.getClass();
      while( !types.contains( exType ) ) 
         exType = exType.getSuperclass();
      System.out.println( exType );
   }
}
```

Output:

```
run:
class java.lang.Exception
class java.io.IOException
class java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
class java.lang.Exception
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)
```

Answer (score 0):

not sure why you want to do this, but:

```
import java.util.HashSet;


public class Test {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    HashSet<Class> set = new HashSet<>();

    set.add(RuntimeException.class);
    set.add(IllegalArgumentException.class);
    set.add(ArithmeticException.class);
    try {
      int a = 1;
      int b = 0;
      int x = a/b;
    }catch(Exception ex) {
      if (set.contains(ex.getClass())) {
        System.out.println("Yes");
      } else {
        System.out.println("got "+ex);
      }
    }
  }
}
```